# How to remove gravity forms style sheets ( wp_deregister_style and wp_dequeue_style )?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here's the current HTML output of my sites.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='gforms_reset_css-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/css/formreset.css?ver=1.7.11' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='gforms_datepicker_css-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/css/datepicker.css?ver=1.7.11' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='gforms_formsmain_css-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/css/formsmain.css?ver=1.7.11' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='gforms_ready_class_css-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/css/readyclass.css?ver=1.7.11' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='gforms_browsers_css-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/css/browsers.css?ver=1.7.11' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I want to deregister this style **gforms_datepicker_css** in functions.php using my codes below but it does not works.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_styles', 100 );  
function my_deregister_styles() {
    if( is_front_page() || is_home() || is_page( 403 ) ){ 
        wp_deregister_style( 'gforms_datepicker_css' );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys .. found a codes that answered my question above. Here's the code to be placed on functions.php

```
add_action( 'gform_enqueue_scripts', 'gform_dequeue_script_list' );
function gform_dequeue_script_list() { 
    global $wp_styles; 
    if( isset($wp_styles->registered['gforms_datepicker_css']) ) {
        unset( $wp_styles->registered['gforms_datepicker_css'] );
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please do not move code behind a link. You should always ensure the relevant code is within the answer, not behind a link. Link only answers are often downvoted and may be removed. See [answer].

Answer (score 8):

You can remove all these files:

```
gforms_reset_css
gforms_formsmain_css
gforms_ready_class_css
gforms_browsers_css
gforms_rtl_css
```

by doing

```
add_filter('pre_option_rg_gforms_disable_css', '__return_true');
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to find where the datepicker hooks into wp_footer and use [remove_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) to prevent it loading.

So for example if i had a plugin that had: add_action("wp_footer","my_function"); to  de-register it i would use remove_action("wp_footer","my_function");